# Are there $f, g$ such that $\int_{S^{1}} |f'|^{2}+|g'|^{2}d\theta-2\int_{S^{1}}f'g<0,$ where $f'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $f,g$ are the functions of $S^{1}$. Are there $f, g$ such that
$$\int_{S^{1}} |f'|^{2}+|g'|^{2}d\theta-2\int_{S^{1}}f'g<0,$$
where $f'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$?

Comment: $f(\theta)=\theta$ is not well defined on $S^{1}.$

Comment: OK, comment deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no such functions. Indeed, if $h$ is periodic and has mean zero, then $\|h\|_2 \le \|h'\|_2$. Take $f,g$ as above and write $g=g_1+c$ with $g_1$ having mean zero. Then
$$
\|f'\|_2^2+\|g'\|_2^2<2\int_{S^1}f'g=2 \int_{S^1} f'g_1 \le 2\|f'\|_2\|g_1'\|_2=2\|f'\|_2\|g'\|_2 \le \|f'\|_2^2+\|g'\|_2^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you! For general constant $C$, are there functions $f,g$ such that $$\int_{S^{1}} |f'|^{2}+|g'|^{2}d\theta-C\int_{S^{1}}f'g<0$$?

Comment: Of course, yes. Take $f(t)=-\cos t, g(t)=\sin t$, then you get equality with $C=2$.